# Clojure: extracting data from xml using clj-xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, clojure

I'm using clj-xpath library for extracting data from xml that comes from a API. As output I'm expecting a mapa of tags and its contents. I have a function that works, here's the code snippet:

```
(use 'clj-xpath.core)

(def data-url
 str "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?" "app_key=4H4Vff4PdrTGp3vV&" "keywords=music&location=New+York&date=Future")

(defn create-keys [tags]
(into [] (map keyword tags)))

(defn tag-fn [tag] (partial $x:text tag))

(defn func-contents [tags root-tag data-url] 
 (map (apply juxt (map tag-fn tags)) (take 2 ($x root-tag (xml->doc (slurp data-url ))))))

(defn create-contents [tags root-tag data-url] 
(map #(zipmap (create-keys tags) %) (func-contents tags root-tag data-url)))
```

However, when I call create-contents it doesn't add the keys

```
(func-contents ["url" "title"] "//event" data-url)

(["http://newyorkcity.eventful.com/events/chamber-music-society-lincoln-center-mixed-wind-/E0-001- 067617553-1?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic" "Chamber Music Society of Lincoln Center - MIxed Winds"] ["http://newyorkcity.eventful.com/events/evil-dead-musical-/E0-001-070989019-4?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic" "Evil Dead The Musical"])
```

And when I only eval its body it gives the expected result.

```
(map #(zipmap (create-keys ["url" "title"]) %) (func-contents ["url" "title"] "//event" data-url))
({:title "Chamber Music Society of Lincoln Center - MIxed Winds", :url    "http://newyorkcity.eventful.com/events/chamber-music-society-lincoln-center-mixed-wind-/E0-001-067617553-1?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic"} {:title "Evil Dead The Musical", :url "http://newyorkcity.eventful.com/events/evil-dead-musical-/E0-001-070989019-4?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic"})
```

Any ideas? Probably the problem is in create-keys function, but I need it because I want a general functon for any set of tags.

Comment: You may want to change your api key now ... SO data is public forever so editing the question won't remove it from the internets

Comment: could you paste in a bit of the api response?

Comment: here it is <search>
<total_items>9980</total_items>
<page_size>10</page_size>
<page_count>998</page_count>
<page_number>1</page_number>
<page_items/>
<first_item/>
<last_item/>
<search_time>0.065</search_time>
<events>
<event id="E0-001-067617553-1">
<title>
Chamber Music Society of Lincoln Center - MIxed Winds
</title>
<url>
http://newyorkcity.eventful.com/events/chamber-music-society-lincoln-center-mixed-wind-/E0-001-067617553-1?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic
</url></event>
</events>
</search>

Comment: And I'll change the API key, yes....